# Laravel - Variable check after form submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

is it possible when submitting a form that redirects me with a variable to check if that variable is null? Because when i have `if($variable === null)` in my code and i dont pass the mentioned variable when loading the page it will result in error that `$variable` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the variable before put it in `if` condition

not in the `if`

**update**:

use this in return : `return view('name_page')->with('variable',$variable);`

Comment: but i am passing the variable from my controller

Comment: put it the code please

Comment: Page controller:
`$variable = null;`
`return view('view', ['variable' => $variable']);`

Form function:
`$variable = 'hello';`
`return redirect('/url')->with('variable, $variable);`

Comment: chack the update

Answer (score 0):

the exception told you that variable doesn't exist on memory so you to check if it exists not in it's value  for that you have change your if condition from

`if($variable === null)` to be `if(isset($variable))`